# Traceroute of Router's own serial port

Tags: cisco, routing, router, cisco-ios, traceroute

[image]I got two routers on my network and I am pinging one router's serial port ip address from that router itself. by checking traceroute I found ping is going outside to neighbor router which is directly connected via serial link on the same port I am pinging.what is the reason of that traceroute behaviour? Image of Router R1, traceroute from R1 to R2, R1 have ip address of 10.1.1.1/24 and R2 have 10.1.1.2/24.

Comment: You need to provide more information. A diagram would be good, and we need the router configurations and traceroute. Edit your question to include these.

Comment: Please, never put text in an image in your question or answer. Copy the text, paste it into your answer, and use the Preformatted Text feature (`{}`) on the text. We need the full router configurations, too.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because of when you traceroute you own IP address on a point-to-point serial interface the ICMP packet goes over the wire to the other side and back.